# use Generator for generating Tuples in java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to get grips on the new java8 streams.

I need to generate an infinite stream of tuples with certain characteristics:

The tuples will have three `int` values, `a`, `b` and `c`.

where `b` and `c` are simply counters, that could be made in a `for` loop with:

```
for (int c = 1;; c++) {
    for (int b = 1; b < c; b++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would then use a filter to calculate `a`

I created a `TupleFactory`:

```
class TupleFactory {
    private static int b = 1;
    private static int c = 1;

    public static Tuple next(){
        if (b >= c - 1)
            c++;
        else
            b++;
        return new MyTuple (1,b,c);
    }
}
```

and then I would like to generate the `Stream<Tuple>` with:

```
Supplier<Tuple> anyTuple = s -> TupleFactory.next();
Stream<Tuple> result = Stream.generate(anyTuple);
```

I get a:

> Lambda expression's signature does not match the signature of the functional interface method `get()`

in the line where I define the supplier...

any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get rid of every instance of `static` in your TupleFactory.  That use of `static` is nonsense.

Then, try this:

```
TupleFactory myFactory = new TupleFactory();
Supplier<Tuple> anyTuple = myFactory::next;
```

If you don't want to fix your `static`s, then this should work:

```
Supplier<Tuple> anyTuple = TupleFactory::next;
```

Comment: Also, keep in mind that it is considered very bad manners to use one-based indexes.  Good gentlemen always use zero-based indexes.

Comment: Thanks, I know, but the problem explicitly forbids the everything zero solution, which though satisfies the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda must provide body for

```
T get();
```

method in `Supplier<T>` interface and handle all this method arguments. But in this case `get` method doesn't have any arguments so there is no need for `s` in `s -> ...`. Instead of

```
Supplier<Tuple> anyTuple = s -> TupleFactory.next();
```

use

```
Supplier<Tuple> anyTuple = () -> TupleFactory.next();
//                         ^^ - means no arguments
```

or maybe simpler use [method references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

```
Supplier<Tuple> anyTuple = TupleFactory::next;
```